# Does the currency in a webshop affect SEO?

Tags: seo, ecommerce

Does a page get **ranked higher** in google, bing, ... if a webshop uses the **user's local currency**?

I am wondering because we are discussing to add more currencies to our webshop. Our thoughts are that the user is more likely to convert (reduces abandoned carts, ...).

**But is there also any effect on SEO side?**

Answer (score 1):

Of course, for global sales, you need to specify the currency of the country in which you sell the goods. In addition, it will be useful for you to adapt all the content of your website to the country in which you sell. Translate your text and navigation with a professional translator. Set the content for titles and alts of your images in the language of this country. And so on.

Of course, apply the meta-links **[hreflang](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077)** to different countries.

All this will allow users from this country to easily navigate your website, in your products and in your commercial offers. This way you will increase the visibility of your website in this country.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use local currency. 
This can improve your conversion rate and also help to increase time one site and reduce bounce rate. Dwell time is a ranking factor, so it's important to keep user satisfied and let them find what they are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of SEO, currency can be of importance only in combination with properly translated and tagged content. Google would only consider content trully relevant to a local target group, as long as everything is made local, including hosting the site on multiple servers, close to your multiple markets.

Currency as an isolated factor wouldn't make much of a difference. It could though hit conversions, as long as it makes the purchasing process more complicated. An optimal solution includes either one-click switch of locale or browser-dependent switch.